# Locate running JRE directory in Windows

Tags: windows, java

Knowing the java version (e.g. 1.6.0_31) how can I *programatically* (from within a Java program) find where the corresponding JRE resides on disk on a Windows machine?

Comment: You can only find where the running Java process comes from.  Java can be installed anywhere on your system. You can search the likely locations...

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer. Or to tell why these answers doesn't fit your request, if that's the case. (Detecting one installation dir among all installed versions?)

Answer (score 2):

It should be available by reading the value of `java.home` system environment variable. See  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html.

But keep in mind that the security manager may block you, from the above link:

> Security consideration: Access to system properties can be restricted
>   by the Security Manager. This is most often an issue in applets, which
>   are prevented from reading some system properties, and from writing
>   any system properties. For more on accessing system properties in
>   applets, refer to System Properties in the Doing More With Java Rich
>   Internet Applications lesson.

Comment: Afaik, you can disable the security manager even from within applets, or has Oracle fixed that leak already? ;-)

Comment: @Peter: I was not aware of that bug - trying to avoid using applets :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.getProperty("java.home");
```

will return you the installation directory for your JRE running the program.

Also check the following link for further information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the current [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) value `java.home`:

```
String installDirOfJRE = System.getProperty("java.home");
```

Based on returned value you can **expect (but just expect)**, that the other versions of JRE will **likely** be in the same parent folder, so you can try to search for the version you would like to find..

I am afraid there is no other option...

Answer (score 1):

```
System.getProperty("java.runtime.version");
```

gives you the version of executing VM.